# Laravel - multiple route paremeters

Tags: routes, laravel-5

There is cases i have nested categories that i don't know the depth. so posts URLs may be `/A/B/post-slug` or `/A/B/C/post-slug` and so on.
 in fact i don't know the depth of URL to add adequate parameters to  [route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing).I need a way to have route with multiple dynamic optional parameters.

```
  Route::get('post/{cat-1?}/.../{cat-n?}/{slug}', 'PostController@show');
```

How should i handle this situation?

Comment: If I guess it right, the only reason you need to this may be because you need these A B C etc in your controller. Then why don't you append these in url? Something like /post-slug?A=A&B=B...Z=Z

Comment: No, im implementing this structure to make my app more SEO friendly,i dont need them in controller

Comment: More SEO friendly? I guess this is what the slug does.

Comment: Can you give a real use case where you need this?

Comment: let's say having `/books/history/europe/Castellio-gegen-Calvin` instead of  `/books/Castellio-gegen-Calvin`

Comment: So what's the problem with  `/books/history/{country}/slug`?